# pivoting and aggregating table lines

Tags: r

I have a dataframe named episodes where each line is a different episode from different subjects (numadm). Each episode has a "start" and an "end" time. A subject can have 1 or multiple episodes (so 1 to multiple lines)

The format of the table is like this :

```
num adm       start     end
```

I would like to obtain a table where each subject (numadm) has only one line, with new columns for the start and end of each episode (start1, end1, start2, end2, start3, end3)

```
num adm     start 1   end 1    start2     end2
```

I read about pivot.wider but not sure how it applies here.

Any ideas?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please see here <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>. To provide example data use `dput()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared any example, let's create a small one

```
df <- read.table(text = "num_adm    start   end
1   a   b
2   c   d
2   e   f
3   g   h
3   i   j
3   k   l
", header = T)
```

Now to get desired result in `tidyverse` do it like this

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(num_adm) %>%
  mutate(d = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(start, end)) %>%
  mutate(name = paste0(name, "_" ,d)) %>%
  select(-d) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = num_adm, names_from = name, values_from = "value")

# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   num_adm [3]
  num_adm start_1 end_1 start_2 end_2 start_3 end_3
    <int> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>
1       1 a       b     NA      NA    NA      NA   
2       2 c       d     e       f     NA      NA   
3       3 g       h     i       j     k       l
```

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please accept and upvote as usually desired on SO.